# Can't start or restart httpd service on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, webserver

I use Fedora 35 and was trying to restart the httpd service but it keeps showing me an error. I've looked everywere for a solution but none seems to be working.

**Apache Version**

```
[root@fedora icaro]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Fedora Linux)
Server built:   Dec 22 2021 00:00:00
```

Here are the outputs of my terminal

**systemctl start httpd**

```
[root@fedora icaro]# systemctl start httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xeu httpd.service" for details.
```

**systemctl status httpd.service**

```
[root@fedora icaro]# systemctl status httpd.service
× httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
             └─php-fpm.conf
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2022-01-27 13:14:27 -03; 3min 6s ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
    Process: 13888 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 13888 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "Reading configuration..."
        CPU: 305ms

jan 27 13:14:26 fedora systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora httpd[13888]: httpd (pid 4826) already running
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**journalctl -xeu httpd.service**

```
[root@fedora icaro]# journalctl -xeu httpd.service
jan 27 13:14:26 fedora systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
░░ Subject: Unidade httpd.service sendo iniciado
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A unidade httpd.service está sendo iniciada.
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora httpd[13888]: httpd (pid 4826) already running
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit httpd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
jan 27 13:14:27 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A unidade httpd.service falhou
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A unidade httpd.service falhou.
░░ 
░░ O resultado é failed.
```

As stated before, I looked everywhere and nothing worked. Please help me.

***Update***

**ss -punt | grep -E ":80|:443"**

```
[root@fedora ~]# ss -punt | grep -E ":80|:443"
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                   192.168.1.10:50250                             52.89.17.198:443  users:(("GeckoMain",pid=3464,fd=64))       
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                   192.168.1.10:55224                             151.101.1.69:443  users:(("GeckoMain",pid=3464,fd=108))      
tcp   CLOSE-WAIT 1      0                                   192.168.1.10:47796                           34.120.208.123:443  users:(("chrome-gnome-sh",pid=3794,fd=139))
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                   192.168.1.10:41316                           198.252.206.25:443  users:(("GeckoMain",pid=3464,fd=159))      
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                   192.168.1.10:47910                           34.120.208.123:443  users:(("GeckoMain",pid=3464,fd=161))      
tcp   ESTAB      0      0                                   192.168.1.10:44920                           108.139.113.74:443  users:(("GeckoMain",pid=3464,fd=163))      
tcp   CLOSE-WAIT 0      0      [2804:29b8:5073:143b:fdd4:6254:be11:d6f6]:44528 [2600:1f1e:fa1:6501:3e3a:64bc:f0b8:a6e6]:443  users:(("chrome-gnome-sh",pid=3794,fd=172))
```

Comment: You already have something running on the ports.

Assuming it's 80 and/or 443, then running the following will tell you what has a handle on them; `ss -punt | grep -E ":80|:443"`. If it's apache, then the correct commend to restart is `systemctl restart httpd`.

Comment: @Bib I did as you said but I don't know what to do with the results. I updated the question with the output as it is too long to put here.

Comment: `systemctl` and `journalctl` show `httpd` is already running on pid 4826.  What does `ps -fl 4826` show?

Comment: after I came across this and tried this fix it worked instantly for me ...
https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-relnotes-content/msg03947.html